# Hibernate Performance GetterFieldImpl

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-batch

I am using Hibernate as a part of a Java Spring Batch application. Part of this batch process involves a number of calls to a postgres database with roughly 1.1 million rows. Each row represents a Java entity of 8 strings and booleans, there are no relations. This process currently takes a few days to run, and I am trying to use VisualVM to see where the performance is bottle-necking.

I am seeing that 90% - 95% of my execution time in this part of the process is in the method org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(). I found the documentation for this method [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/property/access/spi/GetterFieldImpl.html), but I am having trouble figuring out what exactly it is doing.

Is this method getting called as part of getting the objects from the database? If so are there any strategies to change the objects or how they are called to improve performance?

Let me know if there any other information I should include to make the question more useful

Comment: That retrieves property values from entity objects.  If a single job is spending dozens of hours doing that, then it seems highly likely that there is a better way.  We can't really advise you about what that might be, however, without a *much* more detailed idea of what the job is doing, and what the configuration of the database is.

Comment: Perfect I believe that answers my question thank you. Just to clarify I am understanding you correctly you mean that it retrieves values from entities that have already been loaded into memory from the database right? My main goal is to make sure I'm focusing my attention in the correct places, and make sure that its my code and not the database queries that are bottlenecking me at the moment

Comment: To the best of my understanding, yes, it retrieves values from entities that have already been loaded into memory.  But that does not necessarily absolve your queries, in the sense that you may very well be performing the wrong ones.  I mean that in the sense of putting a lot of work on the Java side that could be done more efficiently in the database, or maybe that could be avoided altogether.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean, I'll keep that in mind thank you!